# How to save temporary data in data table then save it to database once the submit button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im new in using data tables in saving temporary data.

I have to save temporary data to the data table first using dropdownlist and add button. Data will only be saved in the database once the submit button is clicked.

How will i able to save first temporary data to the data table using the selected value from the dropdownlist and add button, afterwards, save the data to the database using the submit button?

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                Fishing Ground
            </label>
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddllevelRef" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">-- Select One --</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Albay Gulf"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Asid Gulf"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Babuyan Channel"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Bacuit Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Batangas Coast"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Bohol Strait"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Camotes Sea"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Capiz Coast"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Carigara Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Coron Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Davao Gulf"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Dumaran Channel"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Green Islands Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Guimaras Strait"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Honda Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Island Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Ilocos Coast"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Lagonoy Golf"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Lamon Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Leyte Gulf"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Lingayen Gulf"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Malampaya Sound"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Manila Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Maqueda Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Ragay Gulf"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="San Miguel Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Samar Sea"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Sibuguey Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Sibuyan sea"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Sogod Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Sulu sea"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Tañon Strait"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Tayabas Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Taytay Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Tawi-Tawi Bay"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Visayan Sea"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Moro Gulf"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Palawan waters"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Mindanao sea"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Benham Rise"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Cuyo Pass"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="High Seas Pocket 1"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>


        <td width="40">
            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Validation()" OnClick="lnkSaveReference_Click"
                Text="Add" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" OnClick="lnkCancelReference_Click" Text="Cancel" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvReference" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="rowDelete" HorizontalAlign="Left" PagerSettings-Visible="true"
                CellPadding="4" Width="645px">
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <asp:Button ID="save" runat="server" Text="Save" /></td>
         </tr>
</table>



    Protected Sub lnkSaveReference_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If (Not (ViewState("CurrentDataReference")) Is Nothing) Then
            Dim dt As DataTable = CType(ViewState("CurrentDataReference"), DataTable)
            Dim count As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
            BindGridReference(count)
            ddllevelRef.SelectedValue = "0"
        Else
            BindGridReference(1)
            ddllevelRef.SelectedValue = "0"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindGridReference(ByVal rowcount As Integer)
        Dim Dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Dt.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("Fishing Ground", GetType(String)))

        If (Not (ViewState("CurrentDataReference")) Is Nothing) Then
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            Do While (i _
                        < (rowcount + 1))
                Dt = CType(ViewState("CurrentDataReference"), DataTable)
                If (Dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
                    dr = Dt.NewRow
                    dr(0) = Dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString
                End If
                i = (i + 1)
            Loop
            dr = Dt.NewRow
            dr(0) = ddllevelRef.SelectedItem.Text
            Dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Else
            dr = Dt.NewRow
            dr(0) = ddllevelRef.SelectedItem.Text
            Dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        End If
        If (Not (ViewState("CurrentDataReference")) Is Nothing) Then
            gvReference.DataSource = CType(ViewState("CurrentDataReference"), DataTable)
            gvReference.DataBind()
            gvReference.Focus()
        Else
            gvReference.DataSource = Dt
            gvReference.DataBind()
            gvReference.Focus()
        End If
        ViewState("CurrentDataReference") = Dt
    End Sub

    Protected Sub lnkCancelReference_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As      EventArgs)
        ddllevelRef.SelectedValue = "0"
        gvReference.DataSource = Nothing
        gvReference.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

-- I have to save all the added list on the gridview using the save button ..

Comment: Please post the chunk of code you have tried so far ..

Answer (score 0):

The first one can easily be done using `INSERT INTO` query

For the second:

```
SELECT * INTO Master_table FROM temp_table;
```

where `temp_table` : is the temporary table

Note:

- The SELECT INTO statement copies data from one table and inserts it into a new table.
- Both the column names and number of columns in both the tables are same
- If not then you need to **specify the column names separated by commas**

Comment: i an using array list for the saving of temporary data on the gridview .. i have to save first data in the gridview because multiple data is allowed to be added on the list. All the data added on the gridview will be displayed, it can be edited and deleted.. After all the data are saved on the gridview (as the temporary data storage), it will only be saved to the database using the submit button.

Comment: That means you needed to save the entire content of the grid to the database table on save button's click, isn't it?

Comment: yes , but , i have to save it first on the gridview list .. there is a  add button that will enable the addition of data on the gridview list .. and all the data will be saved in the submit button's click event.